# Android Studio multiple errors related to Android SDK

Tags: java, android, xml

I got Android Studio to begin to learn and develop Android applications and it worked perfectly fine at first. I made a hello world application then Android Studio said something about how I should update some android sdk related thing and I let it do that. Once it completed downloading that update, everything stopped working. Now there is several errors when trying to build any Android project.

Here are some of the errors. MusicPlayer is just the android project. Also, these are errors that come up after making a fresh new project with just a main activity and no cod changes. NOTE: I have already tried completely re installing the Android SDK.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-20\android.jar -M C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package musicplayer.chasesmith.com.musicplayer -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:13: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:14: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:16: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:18: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:23: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:27: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:35: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:39: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:17: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v11\values.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v14\values.xml:31: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:217: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:218: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:220: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:228: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:229: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:230: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:231: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:232: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:233: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:234: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:237: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:239: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:240: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:241: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:242: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:245: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:247: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:248: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:249: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:250: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:255: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:256: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:260: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:264: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:268: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:100: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:102: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:103: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:98: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:99: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:137: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:139: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:135: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:174: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:176: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:177: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:175: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:172: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:212: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
    C:\MusicPlayer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\values-v21\values.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
```

Comment: The combination of `values-v21` and `-I C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-20\android.jar` is what kills you. You don't target v21 in your build.gradle file, you're using just 20.

Comment: That fixed it for me, post that as an answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project uses API level 21 exclusive features, e.g. material design styles in `values-v21` but the project is at the same time only compiled with `android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-20\android.jar` - the prior version, that did not know about material design.

To fix that, up the `compileSdkVersion` (and probably `targetSdkVersion`) in your `build.gradle` file to 21.